# Silverlight / Data form showing one record / what even to use

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Warning - new to Silverlight / RIA Services / etc.

I have a business requirement to show a DataForm with a single record.  In nearly all the examples on the net the dataform is tied to a datagrid on the selecteditem property.

In my case, the form has no grid to tie to.

I know that I'm retrieving data with my ViewModel, but I need a call back to know when the data has arrived in order for the data form to "re-bind" (Winform speak!).  I am also NOT using the DomainDataSource, as I would like to keep everything behind the ViewModel.

I created a CurrentXXXX property, which can only be set after the data arrives.

There is a IsLoading property, but when do you know that data has arrived in the ViewModel?  How do you get the View to rebind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VM implements INotifyPropertyChanged (which it should) then you don't need to rebind as the VM will use this to notify the View that it's changed.

Comment: I thought so, but the binding to the dataform is not "seeing" these event.  Which point to the fact that I have not bound it properly. Being new, I'm not sure what my debugging tools are, other than staring at the declaritive code.  Fiddler comes to mind, but that is  yet another new tool...

Comment: I've seen plenty of Binding errors in the Output viewer in Visual Studio - they can be buried in there so go through it carefully.  I've seen a post about this recently but I can't find it now - I seem to recall there's a setting you can use.  How about posting some code.